# Proof a graph of order $n$ and $\delta(G)\geq \sqrt{n}$ contains a cycle at most 4

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

"If $G$ is a graph of order $n$ and $\delta(G)\geq \sqrt{n}$, then for every vertex $v\in V(G)$ there is a cycle of length at most four in $G$ which contains $v$."

I need to prove this for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, I understand that it can be done using proof by induction but don't know what to have as my induction hypotheses or where to go from this.

Answer (score 1):

Argue by contradiction. If $v$ is not part of a cycle of length $3$ or $4$, then $v$ has $\sqrt n$ neighbors $w_1, w_2, \dots, w_{\sqrt n}$ such that:

- There is no edge $w_i w_j$: such an edge would create a $3$-cycle.
- Aside from $v$, all other neighbors of $w_1$ through $w_{\sqrt n}$ are distinct: if $w_i$ and $w_j$ had another common neighbor, we'd get a $4$-cycle.

Why is this a problem?

(If you're still not sure, try drawing a picture of the argument above with $n=9$ vertices and $\delta(G) \ge \sqrt9 =3$.)

Comment: Thankyou this has helped im still just slightly lost on how to get to the contradiction though, I understand from drawing the argument with n=9 that all edges are connected in order for $\delta (G) \geq 3$ but dont know how to word this for the proof

Comment: If you draw $v$, all of its neighbors, and all of their neighbors, how many vertices do you get?